# JSON data not displaying properly when converting into data frame

Tags: python, json

With my code below when I convert the JSON into a data frame, It returns over 900 columns instead of rows. How would I be able to display it properly in rows and have columns such as URL, link, label? Thanks in advance!

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import json

html = requests.get("https://www.bankofcanada.ca/valet/lists/groups")
json_data = json.loads(html.text)
data_frame = pd.json_normalize(json_data['groups'])
data_frame
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas probably has built in function to do this, but sometimes it's easier to roll your own:

```
records = [{'name': key, **value} for key, value in json_data['groups'].items()]
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(records)
df

                                name                          label                                               link
0                         sdp-2012-8  Staff Discussion Paper 2012-8  https://www.bankofcanada.ca/valet/groups/sdp-2...
1                        swp-2012-37    Staff Working Paper 2012-37  https://www.bankofcanada.ca/valet/groups/swp-2...
2                        swp-2015-46    Staff Working Paper 2015-46  https://www.bankofcanada.ca/valet/groups/swp-2...
3                        swp-2013-42    Staff Working Paper 2013-42  https://www.bankofcanada.ca/valet/groups/swp-2...
4                         sdp-2014-3  Staff Discussion Paper 2014-3  https://www.bankofcanada.ca/valet/groups/sdp-2...
..                               ...                            ...                                                ...
477  ATABLE_INFLATION_CONTROL_TARGET       Inflation-Control Target  https://www.bankofcanada.ca/valet/groups/ATABL...
478     ATABLE_INFLATIOON_INDICATORS           Inflation Indicators  https://www.bankofcanada.ca/valet/groups/ATABL...
479       ATABLE_MONETARY_CONDITIONS            Monetary Conditions  https://www.bankofcanada.ca/valet/groups/ATABL...
480       ATABLE_MONETARY_AGGREGATES            Monetary Aggregates  https://www.bankofcanada.ca/valet/groups/ATABL...
481         ATABLE_POLICY_INSTRUMENT              Policy Instrument  https://www.bankofcanada.ca/valet/groups/ATABL...

[482 rows x 3 columns]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your orientation is index-wise, simply transpose the DataFrame to get 900 rows like:

```py
data_frame = pd.json_normalize(json_data['groups']).T
data_frame
```

Ideally, you'd want to use `read_json()` and then set `orient` to however you want the DataFrame. See https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html#pandas.read_json